# ReactJS: Change html/jsx element dynamically

Tags: reactjs, dynamic, material-ui, icons

I wanna change my JSX element tag dynamically but the remaining attributes stay the same.
Let's say I have something like this:-

```js
import React, { useState } from 'react'
import classNames from 'classnames'
import { makeStyles } from '@material-ui/core/styles'
import DesktopWindowsIcon from '@material-ui/icons/DesktopWindows'
import DnsIcon from '@material-ui/icons/Dns'
import StorageIcon from '@material-ui/icons/Storage'
import CloudIcon from '@material-ui/icons/Cloud'

export const try = () => {
  const classes = useStyles()
  const [changeIconColor, setChangeIconColor] = useState('')  

  const icons = [
    { id: 0, icon: <DesktopWindowIcon /> },
    { id: 1, icon: <DnsIcon /> },
    { id: 2, icon: <StorageIcon /> },
    { id: 3, icon: <CloudIcon /> },
  ]

  return (
    <>
      {icons.maps(icon => (
        <>
          {/* this will work */}
          {icon.icon}
        </>
      ))}
    </>
  )
}

const useStyles = makeStyles((theme) => ({
  icon: {
    width: 100,
    height: 100,
    marginBottom: 12,
  },
  iconMouseHover: {
    color: theme.palette.secondary.main
  }
}))
```

But what I wanna do is something like this:-

```js
import React, { useState } from 'react'
import classNames from 'classnames'
import { makeStyles } from '@material-ui/core/styles'
import DesktopWindowsIcon from '@material-ui/icons/DesktopWindows'
import DnsIcon from '@material-ui/icons/Dns'
import StorageIcon from '@material-ui/icons/Storage'
import CloudIcon from '@material-ui/icons/Cloud'

export const try = () => {
  const classes = useStyles()
  const [changeIconColor, setChangeIconColor] = useState('')  

  const icons = [
    { id: 0, icon: <DesktopWindowsIcon key={icon.id} className={changeIconColor === icon.id ? classNames(classes.icon, classes.iconMouseHover) : classes.icon} /> },
    { id: 1, icon: <DnsIcon key={icon.id} className={changeIconColor === icon.id ? classNames(classes.icon, classes.iconMouseHover) : classes.icon} /> },
    { id: 2, icon: <StorageIcon key={icon.id} className={changeIconColor === icon.id ? classNames(classes.icon, classes.iconMouseHover) : classes.icon} /> },
    { id: 3, icon: <CloudIcon key={icon.id} className={changeIconColor === icon.id ? classNames(classes.icon, classes.iconMouseHover) : classes.icon} /> },
  ]

  return (
    <>
      {icons.maps(icon => (
        <>
          {/* this will not work since it gave me an error saying icon is not defined in array above */}
          {icon.icon}
        </>
      ))}
    </>
  )
}

const useStyles = makeStyles((theme) => ({
  icon: {
    width: 100,
    height: 100,
    marginBottom: 12,
  },
  iconMouseHover: {
    color: theme.palette.secondary.main
  }
}))
```

Is there any ways for me to do this dynamically with React?
Something that can change the icon tag but the remaining attributes stay the same:-

```js
// only tag name changes
<OnlyThisChange className={changeIconColor === skill._id ? classNames(classes.icon, classes.iconMouseHover) : classes.icon} />
```

Is this possible with react?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

yes, this possible.

First of all, you don't need to write a key in the icon component. Prop key must be defined in the Fragment element(<> -> <React.Fragment key={icon.id}>).

Your example is almost correct, one mistake that you're doing is:

```
changeIconColor === icon.id
```

instead of the above example, you can hardcode your ids:

```
changeIconColor === 1
```

Comment: but if i do that it wouldn't be dynamic is it? Imagine having dozens of data. So there's no possible way I could change only the element tag? Or this is the wrong way of doing it?